# Nested elasticsearch query in Java

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say that I've indexed an object that looks like:

```
{
  firstName: "Ben"
  lastName: "McCann"
  urls: [{ canonical: "http://www.benmccann.com" }]
  emails: [{ canonical: "ben@ben.com" }]
}
```

How do I then create a search for "Ben" or "McCann" or "ben@ben.com"?

```
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(INDEX)
    .source(new SearchSourceBuilder().query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("firstName", "Ben"))
        .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("lastName", "McCann"))
        .should(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("emails", QueryBuilders.matchQuery("emails.canonical", "ben@ben.com")))));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a [nested query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-query/) only if you configured the emails field as [nested type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type/) in your mapping. I don't think it makes sense in your case since you have a single subfield under emails, called canonicals. You can just use again a match query and the dot notation, refering to the field as `emails.canonical`.

If you use a bool query don't forget to set the minimum should match, which tells you how many should clauses should match at least out of the ones provided in the query. In your case 1 should be fine.

```
SearchRequest request = Requests.searchRequest(INDEX)
    .source(SearchSourceBuilder.searchSource().query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("firstName", "Ben"))
        .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("lastName", "McCann"))
        .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("emails.canonical", "ben@ben.com"))
        .minimumShouldMatch(1)));
```

On the other hand, if you did configure the `emails` field as nested in your mapping, then you need to use a nested query. I don't see anything wrong in what you are doing, you're just missing the minimum should match parameter.